# C++ Eigen: How to write a function that can both take a regular (dense) Matrix, but also a DiagonalMatrix?

Tags: c++, eigen, eigen3

I have a function that does some linear algebra internally, but I would like to be able to pass both regular dense matrices into it, as well as diagonal matrices (the latter for efficiency purposes).
I tried the following syntax:

```
void bla( const Vector* v, const Eigen::MatrixBase<float>* A, Vector* out )
{
  int colunms = A->cols();
  ....
}
```

but that won't compile because MatrixBase doesn't have a cols() function!

I know that the DiagonalMatrix class has a toDenseMatrix() function, but my concern is that involves an internal copying of values, and thus would nullify all the optimizations I'm hoping to get from DiagonalMatrix.

How would I go about this?

Comment: Why pass pointers and not references?

Comment: I don't see how that makes a difference. The MatrixBase reference still won't have a cols() member function.

Comment: I guess that was meant as a general advice rather than a solution to your problem.

Comment: It was indeed.  I was leaving the answer for someone else.  It seems the possibilities are to dispatch at compile time by overloading the function or at run-time by run-time type checking.

Comment: I find it a peculiar "suggestion" nonetheless, especially when you know nothing about the code base it is integrated in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A general Eigen routine working on any matrix should take the class template `template<typename Derived> MatrixBase` as parameter, which itself takes as template parameter the matrix class which derives from it (i.e., it uses the CRTP pattern). So basically, your function should be set up in a way like

```
  template<typename Derived>
  void foo(const Eigen::MatrixBase<Derived>& x)
  {
      //do something
  }
```

Within this function, as you noticed, you can call only those member functions which are actually available in `MatrixBase`, and `cols()` is indeed not available. However, you can use the members functions `innerSize` and `outerSize`, which depending on the storage scheme behave as ``rows()`and`cols()`, respectively. Read the details [here](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1DenseBase.html#acd9791e1914ad8761992e16032d49c54).

But still if those functions were not available, you could also obtain the desired behavior via overloading of your function. For instance, you could write a general routine taking matrices and using `cols()` as above, and one overload for Diagonal matrices,

```
  template<typename T>
  void foo(const Eigen::DiagonalMatrix<T>& x)
  {
      //do something for diagonal matrices
  }
```

Comment: Thanks davidhigh, those are good suggestions. I will first try the innerSize and outerSize one since it would allow for the most generic version. The overloading suggestion, unless I'm mistaken, would require duplicated code. I guess I am still somewhat surprised that while things like overloaded operators are available in MatrixBase, the cols and rows aren't.

Comment: I agree, `rows()` and `cols()` from the first seem elementary enough so as to include them into the base class. But there might be some reason why they didn' ... since overall Eigen is really well designed

Comment: That depends on what you want to do. If you want to multiply a diagonal matrix with a dense matrix, it won't work like this, as the result is a dense matrix as well. These arithmetics must be reflected by your function. For some further specific questions, please consider to either append them to your question, or better open a new function (with title "product of diagonal and dense matrix", say).

Comment: Hmm, I tried the template version, but then found out that you can't actually do any real computation with MatrixBase. E.g. I wrote a simple test function that multiplied two MatrixBases. The multiplication went through, but you can't print the result without crashing.

I get the distinct impression the overloading is the only way I can do this.

Comment: I also consider overloading -- at least for the one `DiagonalMatrix` variable, whereas the other can be kept general -- to be appropriate. This you are able to multiply matrix-views, say, with your diagonal matrix. But strictly speaking, you must somewhere determine your arithmetics, either via overloading or via template specialization. I'd suggest to open a new question on this.

Comment: It's been 2 years! The latest Eigen (3.2.9) I use has methods such as `cols(), rows()`, etc. available in `MatrixBase` itself, and am using them on a daily basis.